# using pycuda to accelerate the processes work in Qgis

Tags: qgis

I wrote a module in QGIS which I work with the big raster .tiff layers.

I want it to use the video card for processing (not the CPU).

Are there are any ideas how "processing.runalg" can be run in parallel on the GPU?

```
 def change(self):
        var=self.dlg.lineEdit_3.text()
        var2 = self.dlg.lineEdit_5.text()
        processing.runalg('saga:changegridvalues',var, 1, "-100,0,0",var2)
        tif4= self.dlg.lineEdit_5.text()
        layer = QgsRasterLayer(tif4, "rastr_change1")
```

For example using PyCUDA.

Comment: There is already a plugin called CUDA Raster that might do this. (marked as experimental). The raster calculator then runs via the graphics. Directly for your code it will not help. But thats more a problem of the CUDA integration and if the problem at all can be solved by the restricted functions of the graphic card. Graphic processors are not very fast, but highly speciallized and with lots of cores. It all depends on the problem that need to be solved and if it can be run on many parallel threads. Not sure if your problem fits to that.